# Can Stripe support Offline Payments?

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using Stripe for online payments but also users can pay offline (cash or check). I want to centralize all my invoices/charges in one place (Stripe).

I am not sure if I can add offline payments (cash or check) to stripe or not. I guess I can if I created customers, invoices, charges with livemode=false for my live keys.

Is this feasible and will Stripe accept having some (customers, invoices and charges) with livemode=false and others with livemode=true?

If yes, should I fill fake credit card info or should I set it as nil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't currently support offline payments, so you'll want to look at a separate accounting system for those payments.

That said, it's totally understandable that you'd want to keep this data in one place. You might be interested in using our [webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks) system to offer live updates to your accounting system without directly touching the code that creates the charge in Stripe.

Answer (score 3):

Stripe does not allow you to create a Subscription on a Customer if you don't have a credit card setup. More accurately, it does not allow you to create a subscription if a customer does not have a way to pay for the next invoice. So for offline payments, you could update the 'account_balance' on the customer to have a negative value equal to the amount the customer wired (credits). Stripe will then allow you to create a subscription for the customer because it knows that the customer has enough account balance to pay for the next invoice. [This post](https://medium.com/@uttamkini/handling-offline-payments-with-stripe-816f58207a7a#.jq3wmws03) has more details.

Comment: We have marketplace for couriers and we need offline service too